# Geany cannot save files in Desktop Folder

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, geany

Since many years, I always used Geany IDE for code of all kind on either Windows or Linux and been very statisfied.

But then, I decided to use a more recent version and a strange issue appeared in the latest release version for Windows (currently 1.23.1, on Windows 7 Home Edition SP1). Whenever I try to save or create a new file in Desktop folder, *and only this folder and subfolders so far*, it fails with that error:

[image: Error when saving a file]

What I have tried:

- Create + Save files around the folder like AppData, .config, random folders on another drive, etc. (working as expected);
- Compare permissions between those emplacements to find nothing apparently different;
- Looking at Tools>Debug Messages (it says: "Could not find file 'C%3A%5CUsers%5Cusername%5CDesktop%5filename.ext'.", but it can actually read the file)
- Adding specifically a permission to user "Authentified Users";

Is there something I am missing here? Could it be an issue introduced in a recent version of Geany? Any workaround or idea about what could be wrong in my configuration? I was using version 0.21 if I remember correctly and this is the first time I ever encounter this issue. I also searched on many forums to find nothing related to this particular folder in Windows with Geany.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

I came back to release version 0.21 and everything works as expected. There is apparently something different in the latest one that I can't get a grip on yet.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the application.  We wouldn't have been able to help you if thats the case.  Based on the behavior it sounds like the source code should be updated to fully support Windows 7.

Comment: That's what I think too, but I wonder if someone got it to work on Windows 7, since old version's syntax coloring detect some new patterns as errors. Thanks though!